# Hide a file or directory using the Windows API from C

Tags: c++, c, windows, file, filesystems

I want to modify a C program to make some of the files it creates hidden in Windows. What Windows or (even better) POSIX API will set the hidden file attribute?

Comment: Do remember that the hidden attribute is just a hint, and is really only respected by DIR and Explorer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by calling SetFileAttributes and setting the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN flag. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365535%28VS.85%29.aspx

This is not POSIX though. To create a 'hidden' file under a normal POSIX system like Linux, just start a filename with a dot (.).

Answer (score 8):

Windows and UNIX-like systems have different views on what exactly is a hidden file. On UNIX-likes conventionally file names starting with a dot are considered "hidden". Windows file systems on the other hand have a "hidden" attribute for files.

So for POSIX you should probably just create your files with a starting dot in the file name.

On Windows you can use the [SetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365535.aspx) function.

Answer (score 4):

Use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) with the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN flag

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the GetFileAttributesEx, GetFileAttributes and SetFileAttributes set of methods in the Win32 API.

Starting point of the documentation

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946(VS.85).aspx