# How to create a hidden directory

Tags: c++, windows

```
CreateDirectory("C:\\dir",NULL);
```

I can create a directory by the above method but how can I a create a hidden directory?

I tried something like shell execute function to execute the cmd prompt and made my folder hidden but I know that is not the way.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide a file or directory using the Windows API from C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189832/hide-a-file-or-directory-using-the-windows-api-from-c)

Comment: Yes, duplicate. Answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1189876/3919155).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to set the "hidden" attribute to the folder after you created it.

Use [SetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx) function to specify the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` attribute.

According to the documentation, this should work (but I did not test....):

```
CreateDirectory("C:\\dir",NULL);
SetFileAttributes("C:\\dir",FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: On UNIX you'd create a directory with the name starting with a period "." - that makes it a hidden directory.

Comment: True. But I just thought I would mention it to give the asker a more complete picture across different operating systems.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Got it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The command port of hiding a folder or a file is:

```
attrib +h file_name
```

So you can create your folder or file then execute this command on it.

Comment: That is what I did but that must not the way because It first creates a directory and then set the attributes so is there any way to create a hidden folder. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@jpo38's solution didn't work for me, I had to use "**SetFileAttributes**" (with an ending "s").

Btw, if your directory is a std::string, use **SetFileAttributesA**:

```
SetFileAttributesA(myPath.c_str(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
```